# Using function as the argument of another function

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I have on function that has takes another function as the argument:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addition (int a, int b)
{ return (a+b); }

int subtraction (int a, int b)
{ return (a-b); }

int operation (int x, int y, int functocall(int,int))
{
  int g;
  g = functocall(x,y);
  return (g);
}
```

When i use it in the `main` function:

```
int main ()
{
  int m,n;
  int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;

  m = operation (7, 5, addition);
  n = operation (20, m, *minus);
  cout <<n;
  return 0;
}
```

Other ways to use `addition` and `minus` in `operation`:

```
  m = operation (7, 5, &addition);
  n = operation (20, m, *minus);
```

or:

```
  m = operation (7, 5, *addition);
  n = operation (20, m, minus);
```

All of them have the same result: `8` in this case. Are there any differences between them ? What should i use ?

Comment: functions are their own pointers. It's super weird.

Comment: From https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.func *An lvalue of function type `T` can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`.” The result is a pointer to the function.*

Comment: m = operation (7, 5, addition); is more user friendly. IMO